# Rails Mismatch from Inheritence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activesupport, type-mismatch

I'm having mismatch issues with the following setup.

```
class FooBar
end

module Foo
  class Bar < FooBar
  end
end

module Foo
  class Bar  # This throws class mismatch because 'Bar' != 'Bar < FooBar'
    class Abc
    end
  end
end
```

It seems as though having:

```
module Foo
  class Bar < FooBar
    class Abc
    end
  end
end
```

Should work theoretically yet I still get the following output error:

`<module:Foo>: superclass mismatch for class Bar (TypeError)`

`from /Users/amat/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in require`

Comment: From Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.3, this seemed to work fine.  Perhaps the issue is with Rails 4.0.0?

Comment: I agree, this code works fine for me in Rails 4.1.6. Try upgrading Rails.

Comment: Hmmm, well the above code works for me as well in a rails console. Perhaps this is an issue with active_support?